# Showing a system is in Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator

> A force of $F=(8-2x)$ is applied to a $2kg$ object in the
> $X$-direction. It is released from $6m$ away from the $x=0$ point.
> Show that the object is in a Simple Harmonic Motion. And derive a
> formula for its position on the $X$-axis at any given time $t$.

I know that since the force applied is propositional to the distance, this is in an SHM. So **would it be enough to state that $F{\displaystyle \propto }-x$** to prove the motion is Simple Harmonic? Even if it was, I don't know **how to derive a formula for the position**.

Comment: Force is NOT proportional to x. Direct proportionality requires A=kB.

Comment: You do not need the formula for positions. You need the displacement relative to equilibrium position. Displacement of A relative to B=Position  of A - position of B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SHM, there are 2 conditions:

1. Acceleration (or force) is directly proportional to the **displacement from** ***equilibrium position***
2. Acceleration always points toward the equilibrium position.

For any general force $F(x)$ where $x$ is the position relative to some origin (NOT the displacement from the equilibrium position, as commonly used in Hooke's law):

- Find the co-ordinate of the equilibrium position i.e $x_0$ such that $F(x_0)=0$
- Show that $F(x)$ is **directly proportional** to the displacement from the equilibrium position $(x-x_0)$. I.e show that $F(x)=k(x-x_0)$ where $k$ is a constant.
- Show that $k$ is a negative constant (indicating direction is always toward the equilibrium position)

**Note:** in your question, the origin ($x=0$) is not the equilibrium position.